# Extract columns by range and name - R

Tags: r, indexing, range, label, multiple-columns

Assume a `df` with 50 columns, named from `Col_1` to `Col_50`.

I'm trying to extract columns by name and range, like:

```
x <- df[,c("Col_1", "Col_3", "Col_7", "Col_8", "Col_12",
  which(colnames(df)=="Col_15"):which(colnames(df)=="Col_26"),
  which(colnames(df)=="Col_34"):which(colnames(df)=="Col_42"))]
```

It works if I use just names or just range of indexes, but when I use both together it gives the error of "undefined columns selected".

Comment: If Col_1 is the first column, Col_2 is the second column, etc. why you would want to use a character vector to subset? You can just do `df[, c(1, 3, 7, 8, 12, 15:26, 34:42)]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `select` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   select(Col_1, Col_3, Col_7, Col_8, Col_12, col_15:col_26, col_34:col_42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the position of  `Col_1` - `Col_50` is not sequential and not at exact `1st-50th` position then an option in `base-R` could be  as:

```
df[paste("Col",c(1, 3, 7, 8, 12, 15:26, 34:42), sep = "_")]
```